# Enable/Disable Html button based on the data from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am using datatable Jquery and making an ajax call to read data from the server.
Lets say database has 3 attributes "Attribute1 , Attribute2, Status".
Depending upon the Status, the third column on the datatable should be enabled or disabled button.

```
function test(server_url,table_id){
.ajax({url: server_url,dataType:"html",success: function(result){
    var json_obj=JSON.parse(result);
    var Columns="<thead><tr>";
    var Fields=[],Tool_columns=[];
    UserGroupFields=json_obj.columns;
    for(i=0;i<json_obj.columns.length;i++){
        Columns+="<th>"+json_obj.columns[i]+"</th>";
        var field_dic={};
        var tool_dic={};
        field_dic["label"]=json_obj.columns[i];
        field_dic["name"]=json_obj.columns[i];
        Fields[i]=field_dic;
        Tool_columns[i]=tool_dic;
    }
    tool_dic["targets"]=-1;
    tool_dic["data"]="null";
    tool_dic["defaultContent"]="<button this.disabled=true'>Yes</button>";        
    myTable=('#'+table_id).DataTable({
            "order":[[0,"desc"]],
            aaData:json_obj.data,
            dom:  'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            columns:Tool_columns,
            tableTools: {
                sRowSelect: 'single',
                "sRowSelector": "td:not(:last-child)",
                "aButtons": [ {
                    "sExtends":    "editButton",
                    "sButtonText": "Edit",
                    "target":      "#"+table_id
                }]
            },
           "search": {
              "regex": true,
              "smart": false
            }
    });
```

Through above code I am able to add a button to each row read from the server . So how do I now enable or disable it based on the third atrribute of each record "Status".

Type of Data :

```
Object { columns: Array[3], data: Array[2] }
```

Data :

```
[{"column1":"1","Column2":"abc","Status":"Yes"},{"column1":"2","Column2":"xyz","Status":"No"}]
```

Any leads would be appreciated.
I am new to JQuery and JavaScripts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of status in data and set the button in aaData accordingly.

Added one line in your code :

**field_dic["button"]=(json_obj.columns[i]["status"]=="LIVE")?"Button Text":"Button Text";**

```
for(i=0;i<json_obj.columns.length;i++){
        Columns+="<th>"+json_obj.columns[i]+"</th>";
        var field_dic={};
        var tool_dic={};
        field_dic["label"]=json_obj.columns[i];
        field_dic["name"]=json_obj.columns[i];
        field_dic["button"]=(json_obj.columns[i]["status"]=="LIVE")?"<button disabled='disabled'>Button Text</button>":"<button>Button Text</button>";
        Fields[i]=field_dic;
        Tool_columns[i]=tool_dic;
    }
```

Loop to read "Status" value and set the value accordingly.

```
for(i=0;i<json_obj.data.length;i++){
    if(json_obj.data[i]["Status"]=="Yes"){
       json_obj.data[i]["Status"]="<button disabled='disabled'>Button Text</button>";
    }
    else{
        json_obj.data[i]["Status"]="<button>Button Text</button>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(json_obj.columns[i]["Status"]);` logs "undefined" to the console.

Comment: ??...i just gave an example of how you can read status and set the html of the datatable row based on that. If you want exact answer, please share the structure of the data that you are processing. Else try and access the status column and write logic accordingly

Comment: Added the type/structure of data to the question

Comment: Thank you. I was able to read the status value and set the aaData accordingly.  Will add to your code

Comment: Welcome, if you got the solution , please mark the answer as correct one. If you want to edit and add the correct code you can do that also to help the community